# Openpyxl access Excel worksheet by its index

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've googled and searched this question for a while with no success. Is it possible to open a worksheet in an Excel workbook with openpyxl by using its index? For example, I want to insert a photo into the second worksheet for every workbook in my folder. If the sheet name is variable, could I open the sheet using its index? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not really because the order the worksheets might not be as you expect them. Much better to work with the names of the worksheets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, using index to open a sheet is easy.
Check the python code example given below:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook("your path")
sheet = workbook.worksheets[1]
```